# How to make a connection localhost and my database

Tags: database, postgresql, netbeans, web-applications

I'm using NetBeans to make a web application and using pgadmin4 for my database. The problem is when I'm making a connection pool. 
This is my database http://prntscr.com/hzwn9h and I think the problem is because I want something like that http://prntscr.com/hzwnj2 but I have this http://prntscr.com/hzwnrw. I have tried a lot of solutions but it doesn't work and I don't know what else I have to do. One of the things I have tried was this https://rivaso.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/how-to-setup-a-new-database-in-postgresql-and-glassfish/ but unfortunately unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet shows how to establish connection for `PostgreSQL` using `jdbc` driver. Make sure to add `jdbc` driver to libraries.

```
public Connection DBConnect() {
    try {
        String host = "localhost";//host
        String port = "5432";//db port
        String db = "exp";//database name
        String user = "root";//database username
        String pass = "1234";//password

        //connection url
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db;

        //initialize jdbc driver for postger sql
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        //return connection
        return conn;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

reference : [jdbc.postgresql.org](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) { 

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabasename"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,password);

        conn.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: This is for mysql connection